# Equivalence Proof : Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1, W_2, W_3,..., W_k$ be subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space V.

---

**Claim 1:**

If each vector $v\in V$ can be uniquely written as $v = v_1+v_2+v_3 \cdot\cdot\cdot+v_k $ where $v_i\in W_i$  ,

then $\cup_{i}^{k}\gamma_i$ is an ordered basis for $V$ where $\gamma_i$ is an ordered basis for $W_i$

---

**Claim 2**:

If for each $i = 1, 2, ..., k $ there $\exists$ an ordered basis $\gamma_i$ for $W_i$ s.t $\cup_{i}^{k}\gamma_i$ is an ordered basis for $V$, then

$V = W_1\oplus W_2...\oplus W_k$

---

**Question :** above claim is a part of equivalent statement of V is $direct\; sum$ of $W_1,W_2... W_k$. How to prove **Claim 2**?(already solved with **Claim 1**) What surprising is that only with assumption of claim 2, every ordered basis of subspace become disjoint to constitute $direct\; sum$. How could it be possible? I want to reveal this point via proof. Give me slight hint for it.

Comment: What *exactly* is the conclusion of the claim? You seem to have forgotten to add it...

Comment: Nope. I think I didn't miss it. Please check the edited version of body

Comment: DonAnonio was right, and you still haven't fixed it. You are starting a claim with 'If (...)' but miss out on the 'then'-part and *then* quit skip to giving some statement (supposedly alternative to something else, i.e. the missing 'then' part - the words 'More vividly' imply this). It's really hard to make any sense of what you wrote, also partially due to your cumbersome notation (Why would you write a basis in that way? Haven't ever seen this exact notation for a basis) and wording.

Comment: My claim is simple - if each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as a sum of each vector which comes from each subspace, then union of ordered basis of subspace is an ordered basis of $V$.

Comment: plus, I had followed the notation from the book of Insel&Spence. Please recommend me better notation.

Comment: Ah I see, now that you've edited this, the notation seems ok. Since you seem to be new to these formalisms, note that a mere general set has no ordering; you probably mean to write something like 'the elements of $\cup_{i=1}^k \gamma_i$ constitute a basis of $V$'. Also note, that the elements of any finite basis (if viewed as a set) constitute an ordered basis (just pick any order) - I'm assuming by 'ordered basis' you mean a tuple $(b_i)_{i=1, \dots, \mathrm{dim}(V)}$ of elements of $V$.
Another advice: If you're new to this, maybe pick capital letters for sets such as the $\gamma_i$.

Comment: Okay will follow your advice. Does it still miss with conclusion?

Comment: @jackerysmith Yep, you forgot it in your first edition, which is what I read. Now it is clear, not so back then.

Comment: Yes I had clarified some paragraphs&notations which are clumsy